# Validation occurred client side with breeze entities for some properties which will be filled server side in the BeforeSaveEntity

Tags: breeze, durandal

I use the Durandal template in my asp.net mvc solution. The question here is related to Breeze which is also used in Durandal. Let's say I have the following entity in my model:

```
public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I have some properties used to track creation/updates for time and userid (UpdatedById, UpdatedTime, ...). I would like to let the user edit/create my drivers in some data entry pages then fill in these properties (UpdatedById, UpdatedTime, ...) server side automatically in the `BeforeSaveEntity` method.

It works but as you noted I had to allow nullable on the properties like `int?` or `DateTime?` because in case of adding a new entity (everything is blank) the validation failed if I didn't proceed like that.

**My question:** is there another solution or something that could be done to avoid using nullable types on my model (`int?` - `DateTime?`) for these properties which track my creation/edition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make them nonnullable and fill in "dummy" values of the client, in a "registered" ctor for each type that will then get overwritten on the server.